# On page load, is it possible to attach events to elements that aren't in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a table like

```
<table class="table-striped col-lg-12" id="resultsTable" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Include? 
            </th>
            <th>
                Organization
            </th>
            <th>
                Category
            </th>
            <th>
                Orginal File Name 
            </th>
            <th>
                Link to File on Server
            </th>
            <th>

            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="results">
        <tr>
        </tr>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the `tbody` gets built out with `button`s inside its `td`s after the user has triggered a particular event. I think the reason that my

```
$(function () {
    $('table button').click(function () {
        console.log("ok, it got clicked");
        $('#file2Download').val($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text());
        $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
    });
});
```

isn't working is because the `td`s aren't in the DOM on page load. Is there a good workaround for this or do I need to add in hidden `td`s or what?

Comment: Learn about event delegation / bubbling

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use event delegation.

```
$("table").on("click","td",function(evt){ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In a way. It's called event delegation. The idea is to bind to an already existing parent element, but make sure the actual targets of the events match a specified selector. This works because events propagate upwards all the way to the root element of the DOM by default.

Using jQuery's `.on()` instead of `.click`, you can easily do this:

```
$(function () {
    $('table').on('click', 'button', function () {
        console.log("ok, it got clicked");
        $('#file2Download').val($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text());
        $(this).parents('form:first').submit();
    });
});
```

To answer the actual question you asked, no, you cannot attach events to elements that don't exist yet.